# How to change the Grid.Row and Grid.Column of the control from code behind in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the control placed in `DataGrid` like this:

```
<Label Name="lblDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
<TextBox  Name="txtDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
```

How can I change the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` of the control in code behind?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is also a static method to do this (analogous to using the property in code to set a non-attached property rather than using the DP there).

```
Grid.SetRow(txtDescription, 1);
```

You may find this more readable.

Answer (score 43):

Use DependencyObject.SetValue, passing in the DependencyProperty for Grid.Row and the value you want to assign:

```
this.txtDescription.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
```

Comment: I prefer this answer as better answer, because he's used a non-static method.

Comment: I'd also prefer this answer as the better answer because it's non static.